# Database backup with custom code in laravel 5 and get the data upto 10 rows from per table in database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-backups

IN Php I want to get the 20 record from each table in the database using the php code or mysql store procedure .

Any one help..

Thanks

Comment: How and where do you want to store the backup? Another database or a file?

Comment: in the .sql file as a backup like we get from the phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to achieve something.

First of all you have to add the `file` privilege to the user. So you have to login to mysql as root and run this command:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO youruser@localhost;
```

And here's the code that will export each table in a separate file:

```
$tables = ['specs', 'devices', 'categories'];
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $file = '/home/chromespecs/public/sql/' . $table . '.sql';
    DB::statement("select * into outfile '$file' FROM $table");
}
```

I've just tested it and it works.

Comment: Saving sql backups on the publicly accessible PUBLIC directory is not a good idea.Database backups will have sensitive info that noone should be able to access.

Comment: @tix3 yes you are right for that we need to store in storage folder